# When i use nativescript-uuid plugin a get a error

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I get an error that says:

`"TypeError: SSKeychain.passwordForServiceAccount is not a function. (In 'SSKeychain.passwordForServiceAccount(appName, "incoding")', 'SSKeychain.passwordForServiceAccount' is undefined)"`

When i do this:

`const uid = require("nativescript-uuid");
var uuid = uid.getUUID();
console.log("The device UUID is " + uuid);`

I just want to get the device ID of the user device so i can store it.

Comment: Where did you write this code? in methods? Better you show he complete function here.

Comment: I did it in mounted() {} @RalfBordé

Comment: This line `const uid = require("nativescript-uuid");` i imported above the `export default {`

Comment: Are you using latest version of {N} & plugin? Can you share a sample project where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Yes i using the latest version of both @Manoj

Answer (score 0):

1) Install: `tns plugin add nativescript-uuid`

2) This code works:

```
<script>
var plugin = require("nativescript-uuid");

export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      message: "<!-- testpage -->"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    uuid() { // called from a button @tap
      var uuid = plugin.getUUID();
      console.log("The device UUID is " + uuid);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

3) console output: *CONSOLE LOG file:///app/components/Search.vue:32:0: 'The device UUID is **B62CFD5E-C012-49E7-80CA-5DD9D0AC8F10'**

4) you can do this in mounted: too

Comment: https://gist.github.com/AntonFranzen/61953381b61becd7a87ccff6142071fb

Comment: @Anton Franzen You solved the problem ? It's not working with "tns preview" then.

Comment: I think it has to be a problem with my project but i dont know why. And i have the exact same code as you used

Comment: I have now a problem with removing the plugin. Preview is not running anymore. NativeScript encountered a fatal error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SSKeychain'